# MX Lone Star not showing in Grid field options

Tags: 2.7.0, mx-lone-star

According to this [blog post](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/2.7-grid-ready-addons), MX Lone Star is supposed to work with Grid.

However, when I tried changing a field's fieldtype to Grid and set one of the columns to the fieldtype MX Lone Star, I did not see it in the options.

I have already checked the Fieldtypes page and saw that it was already installed.

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: I've seen a number of people mention that some addons listed in that article don't actually support Grid yet.

Comment: UGH! I was confident on upgrading to 2.7 because of fields that were posted there that were compatible. Now it seems to me that I have to find another 2.7 compatible addon to do the job.

Comment: Well I can't guarantee that MX Lone Star was one of them - but I'm just letting you know. It might be a different issue.

Comment: Already sent a message to the developer. Hopefully, he will update the addon. There are some notes in the EE docs about updating the fieldtype to be fully compatible to 2.7(and probably Grid) but I don't want to go into the code and edit. Will be a maintenance nightmare if I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New version is available for download. All bugs with Grid field was fixed. My apologies for delay. Please send me email in case if you will have any errors in future.